# How to set parameter on Runnable then get value?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to set parameter on Runnable then get value.

I wrote this code. When I run this code return **[2, 3, 3]**. Because the thread share temp_value.

Then I added sleep which was comment outed. The result is **[1, 2, 3]**. It works fine!! But.. it is not real multithread, right?

Even it's running multithread, but I need wait the each process finish for the shared value.

How can solve this problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo implements Runnable {
    private int temp_value;
    private ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> newValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Foo(ArrayList<Integer> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      make initial values
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(1);
        values.add(2);
        values.add(3);

//      set values then process and get new values
        Foo foo = new Foo(values);
        foo.startAppendValue(foo);
        System.out.println(foo.getNewValues());

    }

    public void startAppendValue(Foo foo) {

        Thread thread = null;
        int max = values.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            foo.temp_value =foo.values.get(i);
            thread = new Thread(foo);
            thread.start();
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(10);
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//              // TODO: handle exception
//          }
        }
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        newValues.add(temp_value);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNewValues() {
        return this.newValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Callable` and `ExecutorService` to do the stuff

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer> { //Callable is like Runnable but can return value
  private Integer value;

  public MyCallable(Integer v) {
    value = v;
  }

  public Integer call() {
    return value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3); //Creating thread pool with 3 worker threads
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>(values.size());
    List<Integer> newValues = new ArrayList<>(values.size());

    for (Integer v : values) {
        futures.add(exec.submit(new MyCallable(v))); //Submit tasks to worker threads to do stuff in background
    }

    for (Future<Integer> f : futures) {
        try {
            newValues.add(f.get()); // get calculated result from worker thread or block waiting for result to become available
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(newValues);
    exec.shutdownNow();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the answer. It works fine and the code is very simple. I have a lot to learn  from your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `List.parallelStream()`

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      make initial values
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(1);
        values.add(2);
        values.add(3);

        // process each value using multiple threads.
        List<Integer> results = values.parallelStream()
                                      .map(Foo::processValue)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static Integer processValue(Integer i) {
        // do something interesting
        return i;
    }
}
```

> Even it's running multithread, but I need wait the each process finish for the shared value.

Correct, you need to make sure.

- each thread has it's only copy of the data.
- shared collections are accessed in a thread safe manner.

I tried writing this with Threads but it's far too painful to post here.

Comment: I didn't know the choice "List.parallelStream()" it's also good way. thank you.

Comment: @Nori it's much cleaner than using an ExecutorService.

Comment: Yes! It's very simple method!

Answer (score 0):

i think your shared data makes mistake. for this keep i in private space. you can have class like this:
remove temp_value from Foo class and move runnable part to new class named PV.

```
Class PV implements Runnable{
    int index;
    Foo foo;
    PV(int index,Foo foo){
        this.index = index;
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
    @Override
    public void run() {
      this.foo.newValues.add(foo.values.get(index));
    }
}


PV[] pvArr = new PV[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        pvArr[i] = new PV(i,foo);
        foo.temp_value =foo.values.get(i);
        thread = new Thread(pvArr[i]);
        thread.start();
```